# Debugging Intel C++ compiled code with GDB

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, intel, pdb-files

I was trying to debug C++ code which I compiled with Intel C++.
I tried very small Test Program. I compiled with "/Zi" option, I see that *.pdb files is generated but gdb does not show any debug symbol. Even I am not able to break at main() function.

In the forum people mentioned about "idb" debugger for intel. But I do not find it in my Installation area. I have Intel composer edition on one machine and Professional Addition on other. Both places I do not find "idb".

Could anyone suggest any method using which I could debug the code which is compiled with Intel C++.

Answer (score 1):

> I see that *.pdb files is generated but gdb does not show any debug symbol.

Until very recently, the `PDB` format was completely undocumented and proprietary.

GDB never supported it, and is somewhat unlikely to do that in the future (most GDB developers aren't interested in Windows, and most Windows developers aren't interested in GDB).

> Could anyone suggest any method using which I could debug the code which is compiled with Intel C++.

If Intel did a good job of emitting the `PDB` info, you should be able to use the standard Windows debuggers: VisualStudio or `windbg`.

Comment: The `idb` debugger has been replaced with the `gdb-oneapi` debugger. If your Windows application includes support for a GPU the Intel `gdb-oneapi` debugger is used to debug the GPU code. All code that runs on the CPU is debugged using the Microsoft Visual Studio debuggers. Switching between debugging GPU code and debugging CPU code is handled automatically in Visual Studio, if you installed the Visual Studio oneAPI extensions. If you are using VSCode the VSCode `gdb-oneapi` extension only supports debugging on Linux (remotely or locally) and uses `gdb-oneapi` to debug CPU and GPU code.